# Add 2nd hover selector

Tags: css, hover, html-lists

Hi I have created a menu. Added an active class so when a user clicks on the menu icon it highlights the "LI" that the page is linked to.

I already hover selector called before you sign in. The background colour of the UL has been added.

My question is, am I able to add a second hover selector when signing in and changing the background of the UL without it changing the properties set before a user signs in.

Can I do it without adding another css class. Something like ::before or ::after or .active:hover. Would that do the trick?

```
.menuColumn #nav ul li a.active {
  background: #029EF1;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #0175B2;
  color: #FFF;
}
.menuColumn #nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #E6E7E9;
}
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/cwfgzLdt/)

Snippet demo:

```css
 .example1 {
   width: 20%;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: #E6E7E9;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li {
   list-style: none;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   text-align: left;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCED0;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li:last-child {
   border-bottom: none;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #7E7F81;
   line-height: 3em;
   display: block;
   padding-left: 15‌​px;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li a:hover {
   background: #7E7F81;
   color: #FFF;
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #DBDCDD;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li a.active {
   background: #029EF1;
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #0175B2;
   color: #FFF;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li a:not(.active) {
   background: #000;
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #0175B2;
   color: #FFF;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="example1">
    <div id="nav" style="padding-top: 4em;">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test.html" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried the :not selector for UL but that is picking up the properties for the UL for the menu before you sign in.

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

When it is about the `ul` containing the `.active`-class then you will have to use some javascript to change the ULs background:

[The FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cwfgzLdt/4/)

```js
$(".active").parents("ul").css( "background" , "yellow" );
```

```css
 .example1 {
     width: 20%;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul {
     list-style-type:none;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     background:#E6E7E9;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li {
     list-style: none;
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     text-align: left;
     border-bottom:1px solid #CDCED0;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li:last-child {
     border-bottom:none;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li a {
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#7E7F81;
     line-height:3em;
     display:block;
     padding-left:15‌px;
     font-weight:bold;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li a:hover {
     background:#7E7F81;
     color:#FFF;
     box-shadow:0px 3px 0px #DBDCDD;
 }
 .example1 #nav ul li a.active {
     background:#029EF1;
     box-shadow:0px 3px 0px #0175B2;
     color:#FFF;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="example1">
  <div id="nav" style="padding-top: 4em;">
      <p>UL with .active-link in it:</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html" target="_self" title="#" class="active">Active class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p>UL without .active-link in it:</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self" title="#">Example 1</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the background colour of the #nav ul when the active class is being called to something else like 'yellow or green'.

Comment: Hopefully I guessed right this time what you really wanted. See my updated answer.

Comment: Without JavaScript is it possible

Comment: Sorry but the answer is no. You cannot style the parent-element of a certain child-element with pure CSS.

Comment: $(".active").parents("ul").css( "background" , "yellow" ); - Is there a pure JavaScript way to enable this to work.

Comment: There sure is, but I'm not a JavaScript expert, I mostly do my stuff with jQuery, so I can't tell you.